# Finding System.Web.Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an MVC project, In my testing file I can't find the reference to System.MVC.WEB .After finding a similar problem on stack overflow I looked on my computer in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies but files there are XML and not dll files? I also tried Assemblies/Extensions and it's not there either.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546572/finding-system-web-mvc. If you read that article, and tried all the options suggested there, and it's still not working, you need to make that clear here in order to make this a unique question.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading from here [`https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/system_web_mvc_dll.html`](https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/system_web_mvc_dll.html)

Afterwards load the reference from properties in solution explorer.

Comment: Thanks Kenny, that did the job.

Comment: @MosheSommers Good to hear